# TestNG acript not working on FireFox Browser. Same script working on Chrome browser. installed gecko driver

Tags: firefox, testng

TestNG script not working on FireFox Browser. Same script works on Chrome browser.
I have installed new gecko driver. Fire fox works fine on selenium scripts but not on TestNg framework    Can someone please assist.
Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information to your issue including a sample that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am adding Selenium script that is not executed today.  It was working perfect yesterday.  Thank you for any input/help.

Comment: I dont see the code being added. Please edit your question and add the required samples that can help others figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Hello Krishnan, Thank you for your answer.  I was able to resolve the issue.  Can you please help me with another issue I am having.  I am using getting Pop Up when running a Selenium on Chrome Browser.  I can send you the whole details including the code if you can kindly help.  Will be very grateful.